How to extract multiple tables with one query using Power Query M in Microsoft Fabric Dataflow Gen2
We are using an OData connector to try and extract multiple tables from a SAP HANA environment in Microsoft Fabric Dataflow Gen2. Currently we are extracting these tables one by one with separate queries. This is a pain-staking manual process and prone to errors.
It is possible to retrieve a list of tables from the OData connector, but we currently cannot loop over the list of tables because we need to define separate queries in order to get separate tables in our lakehouse.

Is there any way to save multiple tables with a single power query? Or alternatively, is there any way to easily create multiple queries based on predefined data.

Provide the powerquery code to pull the data from a single Odata table, and someone can easily show you how to convert that to combine the data from multiple Odata tables. Note this will be output as one large query. Only visual basic could create separate queries, one for each table, dynamically
